# How to migrate stored procedures in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, migration

I have stored procedures for two complex DB operations affecting multiple tables. Those are directly added in DB. I want them to be added in any new database via a migration file. How can I achieve that?

I thought of writing stored procedures in `queryInterface.sequelize.query` by creating a file with
`sequelize migration:create --name add-complex-stored-procedures`

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
        //SP
    `);
}
```

And then run the `sequelize db:migrate`. But there is no solution available for migrating stored procedures